# How do the parameters to ;. (Cut) work?

Tags: j

What does `<;._1` mean?

```
data=:',MARY,PATRICIA,LINDA,BARBARA'

<;._1 data
```

Comment: Not like I know J, but I assume it has documentation and tutorials explaining the basics like this.

Comment: I am looking for... thx all the same
;. means cut
 _1 is its parameter
the result is a box including MARY,PATRICIA,LINDA and BARBARA

Comment: I remain of the opinion that it is neither consistent nor proper for this question to be closed as "too localized." The rules in the help center do not exclude questions that could be answered by reference to documentation or tutorials. This question should be re-opened for consistency, and because no explanation as to the alleged "localized" quality has (nor can be) provided.

Comment: @millimoose, this question is in no way "too localized." It's broadly applicable to anyone learning J. A question is "too localized" if it only makes sense to the single person asking it. (For example, behavior which turns out to be caused by a specific hardware failure.)

Comment: @CraigStuntz My criterium for using that close reason was "would anyone ever search for the title of the question?" which, originally, wasn't about explaining an operator but a full code snippet. If someone went the extra mile to salvage the question (by making a - correct - guess as to the actual intent) good for them, but I don't feel that questions should be judged for their potential should they be cleaned up as opposed to their merit as they stand. (And they can always be reopened later anyway.)

Comment: @kaleidic The rules in the help center are not an exhaustive reference of moderation practices - there's an organic element to them. Which is why closing and reopening works the way it does, as well as the new "on hold" system - both are to mitigate groupthink/bandwagon closes. Generally [meta] discussions, especially ones with accepted answers by ♦s are better. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a clear consensus on how to deal with "RTFM" questions. (QV for example [thisolder question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;.` is [cut](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d331.htm): `u ;. x y`

`_1` (x) means "split by the first character"; which is `,` in this case

`<` (u) is the verb to apply to each "split". `<` is [box](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d010.htm)

`data` (y) is where you apply the cut.

In other words: "Box each split that is made by cutting `data` at `,`s".